# Why I'm not getting an error when checking the length of null

Tags: javascript, null, logic, logical-operators, string-length

I'm checking the number of digits in a string using the `match` and `length` properties. Here is the codepen with my function http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/redMLE

Initially when returning `numberOfDigits.length` I was getting an error message (`Cannot read property 'length' of null`). I've solved this issue by changing the line to `(numberOfDigits && numberOfDigits.length)`.
This works but I would like to get a better understanding why the new statement can be executed now. Does the interpreter execute the `numberOfDigits.length now?

Also, why are we getting the same errors when the operands are reversed `(numberOfDigits.length && numberOfDigits)`?

Here is the full JavaScript code:

```
function checkLength(str) {
  let numberOfDigits = str.match(/\d/g);
  return (numberOfDigits && numberOfDigits.length);
}

console.log(  checkLength('T3xt w1th sOme numb3rs')  );
console.log(  checkLength('Text with some numbers')  );
```

**UPDATE 1:**
The answers below explained that:

- The order of the operands in the `&&` expression counts.
- JavaScript optimises the `&&` operator and if the first operand evaluates to null then JavaScript does not check the second one as the expression cannot evaluate to nothing else than `null` / `false`.

Comment: This is a condition. The first one must be true in order to run the second. Because numberOfDigits is null (false) the second part won't be readed by the JS engine. Also undefined and 0 (zero) can be represented as false.

Comment: @RaulFernandez And `''` is falsy.

Comment: So, empty string (''), zero (0), undefined, null and false will be represented as false in a condition

Comment: @RaulFernandez You're mixing false with falsy. `Falsy` values are: `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `''`, `false`, `NaN`. The correct way to check if something is `falsy` is to use the `Boolean(falsyValue) === false`.

Comment: My fault, didn't know how to call it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript tries to optimise the `&&` operator:

```
numberOfDigits && numberOfDigits.length
```

If `numberOfDigits` is a falsy value (and `null` is *falsy*), then the entire expression will be *falsy* and there is no need to evaluate `numberOfDigits.length`.

*Falsy* values are: `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `''`, `false`, `NaN`. One way to check if something is falsy is to use the `Boolean(falsyValue) === false` (or more practical but less verbose `! falsyValue`).

---

This is a side effect of the `&&` operator. I can recommend to avoid using it and transform the code to something readable:

```
function checkLength(str) {
  let numberOfDigits = str.match(/\d/g);
  return Array.isArray(numberOfDigits) ? numberOfDigits.length : 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, "the entire expression" will be *falsy*, not false. It will be equal to `null`, to be precise.

Comment: @HugoWood Good tip. Thanks :)

Comment: `Boolean(falsyValue) === false` is a rather verbose way to write `!falsyValue`.

Comment: @user2357112 `Boolean(value)` returns `false` for falsy and `true` for truthy, which is easier to understand in terms of learning (instead of `!!value`)

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin: It might be easier to understand for newbies, but `Boolean(falsyValue) === false` doesn't deserve to be called the "correct way" to do the check. We have too many people thinking comparisons are a different "part of speech" than values and doing things like `if (flag === true) {return true;} else {return false;}`.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for noticing. Now reading your comment everyone will have even a better understanding.

Answer (score 3):

"Does the interpreter execute the `numberOfDigits.length now?"

No, JavaScript short-circuits logical expressions - as soon as result is known (i.e. first operand in `and` is falsy or first operand in `or` is truthy), no further operations are executed in the expression.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

also, beware: `&&` and `||` do not necessarily return Booleans in JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

the reason is that when the interpreter sees two operations connected with a logical and (&&) it will first execute the former, and **only if it is evaluted to true** then it will execute the latter.

that is why since it found `numberOfDigits` to be null, which in JS is equivalent to false, it stops execution and never crashes on `numberOfDigits.length`.

the other way around will, of course, crash.

on a logical OR (||) the interpreter will stop evaluating after the first statement to be true.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason is that the order of conditions counts.

The **numberOfDigits** condition gets evaluated first, so if that is false, the rest of the conditions are not evaluated and you won't get an error.

In the other order you would try to read "length" property of null, generating an error.

Answer (score 1):

"And" logic will be executed as below.

```
true & true = true  
false & anything = false`
```

If first condition fails then there is no point of executing second one.
so it wont execute `numberOfDigits.length` if `numberOfDigits` is null or undefined so no error in the below case.

```
(numberOfDigits && numberOfDigits.length) => false
     false      && anything               => false
```

In same way if first condtion is not null then it will execute second condition.

```
(numberOfDigits && numberOfDigits.length) => true
    true        && true (must be)         => true
```

> Note : In javascript `null` and `undefined` are interpreted as `false`
>   in conditional statements.